# How to use TypeScript version defined in settings.json by default in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

**Requirement**: When opening TypeScript files in VSCode, use the typescript version from `node_modules` instead of VSCode's TypeScript version

In `.vscode/settings.json`, I added the following settings as defined in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions):

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

However, VSCode still uses it's typescript version by default. I've reproduced the issue in [vscode-typescript-default-version](https://github.com/trivikr/vscode-typescript-default-version) repository.

What needs to be done to use typescript version from `node_modules` by default when opening TypeScript files in VSCode?

Trivikram

Answer (score 9):

When you have opened a typescript file, click on typescript version on the right bottom corner of vscode, and select `Use Workspace Version`.

[image]

If you need this configuration as default to all typescript files on vscode put the configuration on "User Settings" (ctrl+,).

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

In my case I have this file in `~/.config/Code/User`. If you open a file on a directory whithout `node_modules/typesript/lib` a warning is shown:

> The path /home/jahuuar/test/node_modules/typescript/lib doesn't point
>   to a valid tsserver install. Falling back to bundled TypeScript
>   version.

Comment: Thanks @jahuuar for the answer, but the question is what needs to be done that VSCode picks typescript version from node_modules **by default**

Comment: I understand. See my edited answer and remember to config in User Settings, not in Workspace Settings.

Comment: Thanks @jahuuatr , even if it's possible in User Settings the developer has to explicitly set it. I'm wondering if it's possible to override Typescript version in workspace settings by default.

Comment: I plan to create an issue with Github if that isn't possible https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode, I opened a question on StackOverflow as that's what VSCode issue template had recommended

Comment: @Trivikram probably `User Settings` will work only with a globally installed Typescript (local paths are just ignored in this case). If you want to use a local version - workspace settings are for that

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue with VSCode showing a lot of typescript errors even though typescript was compiling my code just fine. The problem was that VSCode updated their typescript SDK to version 5 while my project was only meant to be using typescript 4.

To answer your question on whether you can force VSCode to use the workspace typescript by default: You can't.

[Someone requested this feature in the VSCode github repo and it was rejected](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172732). I am using VSCode 1.77.1 and this feature still has not been implemented.

The only "solution" is to use the workaround described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75357623/6735035) stackoverflow answer:

> The best you can currently do is:
>
> ```json
> "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib",
> "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
> ```