# NestJS project conversion front-end to back-end

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I found [this](https://github.com/Clarvel/TennoTyper) library and am trying to make it into a back-end with NestJS. This is the first time I am doing something like this and I am running into quite a few issues... Right now the real issue I am having is that I cannot use an API call, since there is an error in the tsconfig that blocks progress. I have seen this error on the typescript github posted quite a few times... Since 2017 and still no solution is provided... The issue I am talking about is `Option 'allowJs' cannot be specified with option 'declaration'.` which seems to be a returning issue in typescript. How do I handle this? I am trying to send in 2 strings to the api and return a constructed image. [Github](https://github.com/GrimZero/tenno-typer)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was [fixed in 3.7](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7546#issuecomment-535699638), I see in [your `package.json`](https://github.com/GrimZero/tenno-typer/blob/master/package.json) that you're on 3.6, you could upgrade to `typescript@beta` or `typescript@rc` as those are 3.7 at the moment and that will fix it.

Comment: Are you sure this was fixed? i have tried updating my typescript to both versions and the error remains the same.

Comment: I tried it myself, after upgrading the TypeScript version the tsconfig error didn't show up anymore. Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: I am getting it when running the ```nest start``` command. It gets dropped into the console.

Comment: Those are other errors, not from the `tsconfig`. They're from the `index.js` file.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the exact error I am seeing to my initial post.

Comment: Ah, in VS Code. Did you tell VS Code to use the TypeScript version in your workspace folder, instead of its own?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I know how to do that. I'm trying to find out which one it is using. because that seeems possible. I have tried this just now. I don't know what else I would need to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810894/how-to-force-vscode-to-use-locally-installed-typescript

Comment: When you have a TypeScript file open, in the bottom right corner the version will be displayed and you can click on it to change it.

Comment: Ok, I just checked. I have now changed the vscode version on the bottom to reflect the beta. I am still getting the same error though. maybe its not the vscode that needs to know the version but nestjs itself?

Comment: Try reloading VS Code.

Comment: index.js line 3: Declaration emit for this file requires using private name '(Anonymous function)'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit. *confused screaming*