# VSCode Typescript Version and linter not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

On Visual Studio code IDE I had the following issues:

- The TypeScript version at the bottom right of the screen was not showing.
- Linter not working for any of my projects.
- "Typescript : Select Typescript Version" setting was missing from the command palette

This is after trying the suggestions from other stackoverflow articles:

- [How to force VSCode to use locally installed TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810894/how-to-force-vscode-to-use-locally-installed-typescript)

And lastly attempting to follow along with VSCodes documentation in order to attempt to fix the problem.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Installing typescript globally did not rectify this issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve my issue by completely uninstalling VS Code, getting the latest version and installing it. steps:

Windows:

1. Control panel > Uninstall a program > VSCode
2. Delete directory C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\Code
3. Delete directory C:\Users{user}.vscode
4. Download and install latest from: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Success!

Answer (score 2):

I found myself in a similar situation, except other projects worked. The solution in my case was to search for the `@builtin typescript` extension and choose "Enable (Workspace)" from the contextual menu ("Enable" is grayed out). Still not sure why it was disabled for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your root folder in VSCode has to be the one containing `node_modules` folder in order for it to recognize that you have a workspace verions of typescript.

And if the command is missing from your palette, its probably because you are not in a typescript file. Open a ts file and then search the command palette again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discovered that at some point I had disabled the `@builtin` `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features`. Enabling it again fixed the issue.