# VS Code 1.87 update shows problem in Copilot temp files

Tags: visual-studio-code

After latest update to vscode it shows problems in files that are not part of my project:

[image]

To me it looks like it is finding errors in Copilot temp files? It did not happen before the update.

[image]

If I use the context menu to copy an issue I get:

```
[{
    "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2304",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find name 'projectsPath'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 32,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 44
},{
    "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2304",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find name 'projectUsersPath'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 62,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 78
},{
    "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2304",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find name 'documentsPath'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 89,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 102
},{
    "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2304",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find name 'getFirestore'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 27,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2552",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find name 'collectionKey'. Did you mean 'collectionRef'?",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 60,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 73,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 3,
            "startColumn": 11,
            "endLineNumber": 3,
            "endColumn": 24,
            "message": "'collectionRef' is declared here.",
            "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2304",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot find name 'Doc'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 9,
    "startColumn": 61,
    "endLineNumber": 9,
    "endColumn": 64
}]
```

Example of one of the "files":

```
public static async fetchWithRetry(url, maxRetries = 3) {
    for (let i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            if (i === maxRetries - 1) { // If last retry, throw error
                throw error;
            }
            this.delay(100 * (i + 1));
            console.error(`Fetch failed, retrying... (${i + 1}/${maxRetries})`, error);
        }
    }
    return null; // Add this line
}
```

Example of tsconfig.json in project where this happens:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2018"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2018",
        "baseUrl": "", // needed to avoid nodejs conflicts between different firebase modules
        "paths": { //  - dito
            "*": [
                "@types/*"
            ]
        },
      "noImplicitAny": false
  },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "src",
        "src/typings.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: absolute paths please. You can copy the JSON representation of the problem by using the corresponding context menu item for the problem in the problems panel

Comment: okay unfortunately those aren't absolute paths. please give the absolute paths to those files as well like I asked.

Comment: But how can I give absolute paths? If I option click one of the errors it opens a file called 7dcc4f95-ccd8-407b-b3f6-e0490ce3d45e. It contains 12 line of code that are part of a several 100 lines long file. If I right click the tab, I don't get an "Open in FInder" option. If I click "Find file reference" it opens a references pane that contain "No results".

Comment: this smells like virtual documents then, and not a file under the `.git` folder. if there's really no absolute path.

Comment: please show a minimal tsconfig.json file for a [mre]. also, does this happen if you install a lower typescript version for your project and specify its tsdk in vscode settings? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74642723/11107541

Comment: Same issue here but I think these are Copilot generated snippets that somehow get processed as files and naturally have a bunch of issues since they are just snippets (in addition to being AI-generated and potentially wrong). Not sure how to fix this, but maybe this helps narrow it down.

Comment: are you using copilot? how large are these "files"? please show their contents if they are not too long. maybe you can check if they are actually git-internal files by using https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file ?

Comment: I have added the requested info to the original question. I am using Copilot and I think is has something to do with Copilot. It look like the "files" contains code that I recently marked and asked Copilot a question about.

Comment: check out my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78115479/11107541. cc @AlanMendelevich

Comment: While waiting for a fix in next version of VScode, I suggest using a glob to unmatch these temp files. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78161551/657764, but basically exclude the glob `[a-f0-9]*` and you are done!