# Why do I have a bunch of untracked files in my source control, files that I didn't create or modify that are not supposed to exist in my project?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore, sonarlint

[image]

I would like it to not add those untracked files to my project.

I just imported the project from GitLab, change some things, and it adds all of that.
From what I see, the files are mostly empty and are stored in `.idea\sonarlint\issuestore`.
I want it to stop doing that.

Comment: Because you're using a JetBrains IDE; that's where they put various working files. If you don't want them, gitignore them (locally or globally).

Comment: please provide the full paths to these files. if there are no parent directories for these files, and you're using GitHub Copilot, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78115479/11107541.

Comment: there is a `.idea/.gitignore`, should it not ignore all content of this sub directory

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these files are used by your IDE to track things. Add folder idea in .gitignore file